# in google search box which event fire?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in google search box when we typing something ,   On that time some auto complete  result coming  after select any one it automatically fire no need to

> `focusout()`

or

> any `click()`

how it create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically three key related events keydown, keypress and keyup, it is using combination of these events... To make you understand more here is the detail

`keydown` is fired when the key is down (like in shortcuts; for example, in `Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl` is held 'down'.

`keyup` is fired when the key is released (including modifier/etc keys)

`keypress` is fired as a combination of `keydown` and `keyup`, or depending on keyboard repeat (when `keyup` isn't fired). (this repeat behaviour is something that I haven't tested. If you do test, add a comment!) If user keep key pressed, then this event is fired for every character added by the browser.

**NOTE:** Remember one thing, if you are fetching the value from the field never ignore the keyup event, because while getting text of the input you won't get the last type character from the textfield until keyup event is fired...

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zG9MF/2/) to get more idea about key events..